# Cannot send drafts from Outlook, permission error

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

We upgraded to Exchange 2010 SP1 this summer, and I have noticed an odd behavior with drafts in Outlook 2007 since. A user just reported to me this morning that it happened in OWA as well. Certain emails saved as drafts, when you open them and try to send them, results in the following error:

**Cannot send this item. You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.**

Why wouldn't I have permission to send an email saved in my drafts folder? This doesn't happen to every draft, but it is not uncommon.

Is there a configuration issue? Do I really not have permission, or is this a bug or known issue?

Clarification: Email is being sent as my user, by me. Same for the user that encountered this. Not sending as someone else.

**Attached receive connector output from EMS:**

```
RunspaceId                              : 61a13e50-9572-43ca-8d2b-a75f6a897a7c
AuthMechanism                           : Tls, Integrated, BasicAuth, BasicAuthRequireTLS, ExchangeServer
Banner                                  : 220 mail.apriori.com
BinaryMimeEnabled                       : True
Bindings                                : {:::25, 0.0.0.0:25}
ChunkingEnabled                         : True
DefaultDomain                           :
DeliveryStatusNotificationEnabled       : True
EightBitMimeEnabled                     : True
BareLinefeedRejectionEnabled            : False
DomainSecureEnabled                     : False
EnhancedStatusCodesEnabled              : True
LongAddressesEnabled                    : False
OrarEnabled                             : False
SuppressXAnonymousTls                   : False
AdvertiseClientSettings                 : False
Fqdn                                    : CONSVEXG01.fbc.com
Comment                                 :
Enabled                                 : True
ConnectionTimeout                       : 00:10:00
ConnectionInactivityTimeout             : 00:05:00
MessageRateLimit                        : unlimited
MessageRateSource                       : IPAddress
MaxInboundConnection                    : 5000
MaxInboundConnectionPerSource           : unlimited
MaxInboundConnectionPercentagePerSource : 100
MaxHeaderSize                           : 64 KB (65,536 bytes)
MaxHopCount                             : 60
MaxLocalHopCount                        : 12
MaxLogonFailures                        : 3
MaxMessageSize                          : 10 MB (10,485,760 bytes)
MaxProtocolErrors                       : 5
MaxRecipientsPerMessage                 : 5000
PermissionGroups                        : AnonymousUsers, ExchangeUsers, ExchangeServers, ExchangeLegacyServers
PipeliningEnabled                       : True
ProtocolLoggingLevel                    : None
RemoteIPRanges                          : {::-ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff, 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255}
RequireEHLODomain                       : False
RequireTLS                              : False
EnableAuthGSSAPI                        : False
ExtendedProtectionPolicy                : None
LiveCredentialEnabled                   : False
TlsDomainCapabilities                   : {}
Server                                  : CONSVEXG01
SizeEnabled                             : EnabledWithoutValue
TarpitInterval                          : 00:00:00
MaxAcknowledgementDelay                 : 00:00:30
AdminDisplayName                        :
ExchangeVersion                         : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Name                                    : Default CONSVEXG01
DistinguishedName                       : CN=Default CONSVEXG01,CN=SMTP Receive Connectors,CN=Protocols,CN=CONSVEXG01,C
                                          N=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrativ
                                          e Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configura
                                          tion,DC=fbc,DC=com
Identity                                : CONSVEXG01\Default CONSVEXG01
Guid                                    : b250524b-a0c0-4e80-8427-5d1c52c18c42
ObjectCategory                          : fbc.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Smtp-Receive-Connector
ObjectClass                             : {top, msExchSmtpReceiveConnector}
WhenChanged                             : 8/19/2011 1:51:50 AM
WhenCreated                             : 8/16/2011 9:06:11 PM
WhenChangedUTC                          : 8/19/2011 5:51:50 AM
WhenCreatedUTC                          : 8/17/2011 1:06:11 AM
OrganizationId                          :
OriginatingServer                       : consvdc01.fbc.com
IsValid                                 : True

RunspaceId                              : 61a13e50-9572-43ca-8d2b-a75f6a897a7c
AuthMechanism                           : Tls, Integrated, BasicAuth, BasicAuthRequireTLS
Banner                                  : 220 mail.apriori.com
BinaryMimeEnabled                       : True
Bindings                                : {:::587, 0.0.0.0:587}
ChunkingEnabled                         : True
DefaultDomain                           :
DeliveryStatusNotificationEnabled       : True
EightBitMimeEnabled                     : True
BareLinefeedRejectionEnabled            : False
DomainSecureEnabled                     : False
EnhancedStatusCodesEnabled              : True
LongAddressesEnabled                    : False
OrarEnabled                             : False
SuppressXAnonymousTls                   : False
AdvertiseClientSettings                 : False
Fqdn                                    : mail.apriori.com
Comment                                 :
Enabled                                 : True
ConnectionTimeout                       : 00:10:00
ConnectionInactivityTimeout             : 00:05:00
MessageRateLimit                        : 5
MessageRateSource                       : User
MaxInboundConnection                    : 5000
MaxInboundConnectionPerSource           : 20
MaxInboundConnectionPercentagePerSource : 2
MaxHeaderSize                           : 64 KB (65,536 bytes)
MaxHopCount                             : 60
MaxLocalHopCount                        : 12
MaxLogonFailures                        : 3
MaxMessageSize                          : 10 MB (10,485,760 bytes)
MaxProtocolErrors                       : 5
MaxRecipientsPerMessage                 : 200
PermissionGroups                        : ExchangeUsers
PipeliningEnabled                       : True
ProtocolLoggingLevel                    : None
RemoteIPRanges                          : {::-ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff, 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255}
RequireEHLODomain                       : False
RequireTLS                              : False
EnableAuthGSSAPI                        : True
ExtendedProtectionPolicy                : None
LiveCredentialEnabled                   : False
TlsDomainCapabilities                   : {}
Server                                  : CONSVEXG01
SizeEnabled                             : Enabled
TarpitInterval                          : 00:00:00
MaxAcknowledgementDelay                 : 00:00:30
AdminDisplayName                        :
ExchangeVersion                         : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
Name                                    : Client CONSVEXG01
DistinguishedName                       : CN=Client CONSVEXG01,CN=SMTP Receive Connectors,CN=Protocols,CN=CONSVEXG01,CN
                                          =Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative
                                           Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configurat
                                          ion,DC=fbc,DC=com
Identity                                : CONSVEXG01\Client CONSVEXG01
Guid                                    : 1b0ae4c8-ee30-4a76-878c-58459ae0edf8
ObjectCategory                          : fbc.com/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Smtp-Receive-Connector
ObjectClass                             : {top, msExchSmtpReceiveConnector}
WhenChanged                             : 8/19/2011 1:51:20 AM
WhenCreated                             : 8/16/2011 9:06:11 PM
WhenChangedUTC                          : 8/19/2011 5:51:20 AM
WhenCreatedUTC                          : 8/17/2011 1:06:11 AM
OrganizationId                          :
OriginatingServer                       : consvdc01.fbc.com
IsValid                                 : True
```

Environment:

- Outlook 2007 SP2
- Exchange 2010 SP1

Comment: are these emails being "sent as" another user?

Comment: No, no delegation or other user involved...but that is what it seems like.

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your receive connectors please?

Comment: @Paul Ackerman - Attached

Comment: nobody has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug.

**Cause**

> The issue occurs because the email message item is saved as read-only. When the Exchange server tries to change this property of the cached message item, the operation fails.

Update Rollup 5 version 2 for Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 2 (SP2) should fix that.

**Suggested Workaround**

1. From the **Drafts** folder, open the draft version of the email message.
2. On the Ribbon, click the **Format Text** tab.
3. In the **Format** area, click **Rich Text**.
4. Save and then close the message.
5. Reopen the message, and then, on the Ribbon, click the **Format Text** tab.
6. In the **Format area**, click **HTML**, and then save the message.
7. Reopen and then send the message.

See [KB2763886](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2763886/en).

Comment: Please expand upon your answer please.  In general we expect answers to provide detailed responses and not a pointer or link to another site.